# Magento 1.9.3.1 no navigation bar in admin

Tags: magento-1.9, admin

My adminhtml/backend nav menu gone missing suddenly.

In page source there is no nav-bar at all.

Comment: Have you check user Roles?

Comment: Checking  right now :(

Comment: any console error

Comment: Nope, nothing :(

Comment: did you disable any modules under `System > configuration > Advanced > Advanced` ?

Comment: No menu at all, no access to any menu in backend ;(

Comment: Already disabled or changed settings directly in database but no luck ;(

Comment: Tried clone live but it still not displayed menu so I think it might be a problem in ... database ?????

Comment: Can't find any issue, nav-bar still won't appear :(